# Mark an action to be remembered as soon as privileges are sufficient

Tags: feature-request

If users are lacking privileges to execute a specific action (upvote, downvote, editing), they should be provided with the possiblility to mark the action in a way that se remembers them as soon as they have gained the privilege to execute the action.

Pro arguments include:

- no need to keep a separate list of pending actions (I'm currently doing this, especially regarding comments)
- all necessary controls can put in the popup dialog which notifies about the missing privileges, so no dramatic change of the appearance

Argument which can be used for both pros and cons:

- looking at the list of pending actions might be both motivating and frustrating

EDIT 1: I'm not referring to possibilities to request peer review, only to my own actions.

Answer (score 9):

The system already does something along these lines in some cases by converting your desire into a lesser action that has to be reviewed.

- If you don't have the reputation to edit then you suggest an edit for peer review.
- If you don't have the reputation to **vote** to close then you can **flag** to close which puts the question on the close review queue.

These actions are immediate and reviewed.

Other actions aren't converted into lesser actions (like voting) because there are no lesser actions for them to convert to and also the reputation requirements (15 for vote up, 50 for commenting everywhere and 125 for vote down for example) aren't difficult to achieve.

Queuing actions wouldn't make sense as it could be days, weeks or even months later when you reach the reputation threshold and the action you wanted to perform might be incorrect by that time.

In the meantime you can always "favorite" the question and remember to review it later when you do have the reputation.

Comment: Why shouldn't I have an interest to comment a question after half a year (it might still be worth improving) - of course there will be obsolete entries in the queue at the time the reputation is sufficient?

Comment: @KarlRichter - Yes you might have an interest, but your potential comment from half a year ago might be redundant at best.

Comment: @KarlRichter The point is that *if* you still have interest to comment after half a year *and* that comment is still valid, you have to do it conciously and not have the system automagically perform a million votes/comments on your behalf once you gain some privilege. And if you do it conciously, you can as well think throroughly about it and thus read the favourited question/answer again *to be sure* your upvote/comment is indeed valid.

Comment: @ChristianRau I never mentioned "automagically perform" any action, I've been talking about a function to remember and to mark actions to be handled individually later!! If I mark it as favorite question I will hardly remember what I wanted to do after a year.